# How do I completely reset my TFS settings?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, tfvc

For some context, you can see my other question here: [How do I change the local path of a subfolder in TFS (not the whole workspace)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532203/how-do-i-change-the-local-path-of-a-subfolder-in-tfs-not-the-whole-workspace)

To sum up, it seems I've encountered some kind of TFS bug. I mapped a subfolder of a TFS project to a local path and I can't seem to sever that connection. I tried deleting the local folder from File Explorer. I even erased every VS-related folder I could find from my AppData, causing Visual Studio to forget all of its recent projects and solutions and everything, and still it remembers this local path. But when I right-click the folder in Source Control Explorer, it gives a "Map to Local Folder..." option but no "Remove Mapping" option like it's supposed to.

[image: Advanced > Map to Local Folder...]

Is the memory of this mapping stored online somewhere? How do I reset everything and make it as though I'm opening this TFS project for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the issue in Source Control explorer, there is a feedback: [Manage Workspace Issues - Changing the Local Path of a Project](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/119805/manage-workspace-issues-changing-the-local-path-of.html).

You can get the latest version by clicking **Get Latest Version** option (your screenshot), then the files will be in the correct folder and the cache will be updated, then you will find the path is changed in Source Control explorer.

Another way is that you can remove this workspace and create a new workspace.

Comment: I had removed all workspaces and even deleted all AppData folders relating to VS or TFS. Source Control Explorer still remembered that old path somehow.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Did you get the latest version by clicking Get Latest Version option?

Comment: Wouldn't that get the latest version into the folder that it's saying it's mapped to?

Comment: @KyleDelaney No, the files will be download to the correct path and the path in source control explorer will be updated.

Comment: Okay, but the question remains. Where is that path string that it's displaying stored? It doesn't seem to be in AppData, since the incorrect path string persisted after I went and deleted the AppData files.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I can't clear it too after deleting the files in AppData, such as AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation, AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio, AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio. You may track that feedback.

Comment: I'll accept this answer even though it doesn't exactly answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Go to > File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control..
may be by using this you can able to remove.

**Or You may follow this other way**

To remove Completely TFS source control binding by following only two steps:

**Step-1 :-** Go to your solution's folder, find and delete all files having extensions *.vssscc and *.vspscc

**Step-2 :-** open your solution's .sln file in notepad then find and remove this "GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)" section.

Comment: File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control doesn't exist, so I'm guessing you mean I should edit the workspace. Currently no local mappings show up when I do that. Also, there's no solution folder for me to go to. I've deleted my local copy of the files.

Comment: Okay can you provine me team viewer ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.